How can I ensure my Google Apps Script merges cells in the final rows as expected?
I'm trying to use Google Apps Script to merge cells in Google Sheets when multiple rows have the same values in a specific column. My goal is to merge the cells in the other columns based on matches in one column (specifically, the second column at index 1). If multiple rows share the same value in this column, I want to merge the values of the other columns for those rows.
The following script works as expected, except for one condition: if the rows with the same values in the second column (the target column) are the last rows in the sheet, it doesn’t merge them like it does for other rows that are not at the end.
Thanks to @Tanaike who provided the following script
function mergeCustomerOrderRows() {
  const spreadsheetId = "GOOGLE_SHEET_ID";
  const sheetName = "SHEET_NAME";
  const mergeColumns = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
  const checkCol = 2; // Column "B". This is from your script.

  try {
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName);
    const values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    let temp = "";
    let tempAr = [];
    const ar = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      const v = values[i][checkCol - 1];
      const row = i + 1;
      if (v == temp) {
        tempAr.push(row);
      } else {
        if (tempAr.length > 0) {
          ar.push(tempAr);
        }
        tempAr = [row];
        temp = v;
      }
      if (i == values.length - 1 && tempAr.length > 0) {
        ar.push(tempAr);
      }
    }
    ar.filter(r => r.length > 1).forEach(r => {
      const start = r.shift();
      const end = r.pop();
      mergeColumns.forEach(m => {
        const range = sheet.getRange(`${m}${start}:${m}${end}`);
        if (!range.isPartOfMerge()) {
          range.merge();
        }
      });
    });

    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    Logger.log("Merging completed based on the second column match.");
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Merged cells successfully based on second column condition");
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log(`Error: ${error.message}`);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(`Error: ${error.message}`);
  }
}

Is there a way to adjust the code so it includes the last rows if they meet the criteria? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

It looks like you included code from somewhere else. If you're using someone else's work without giving them credit, that constitutes plagiarism, which is not welcome on Stack Exchange. To fix it, [edit] to make sure you do ALL the following: 1.Include a link to the source, 2. Mention the author's name, and 3. Quote the copied content. For more details, see referencing help and this FAQ.

I edited my post to gave the real author a credit

In your situation, how about the following modification? In this modification, I used the sample script from this post (Author: me).
Modified script:
function mergeCustomerOrderRows() {
  const spreadsheetId = "GOOGLE_SHEET_ID";
  const sheetName = "SHEET_NAME";
  const mergeColumns = { start: "A", end: "E" }; // Columns "A", "B", "C", "D", and "E".
  const checkCol = 2; // Column "B". This is from your script.

  try {
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName);
    const srcRange = sheet.getDataRange();
    const values = srcRange.getValues();
    srcRange.getMergedRanges().forEach((r) => {
      const startRow = r.getRow() - 1;
      const endRow = startRow + r.getNumRows() - 1;
      const startCol = r.getColumn() - 1;
      const endCol = startCol + r.getNumColumns() - 1;
      const v = values[startRow][startCol];
      for (let r = startRow; r <= endRow; r++) {
        for (let c = startCol; c <= endCol; c++) {
          if (!values[r]) {
            values[r] = [];
          }
          values[r][c] = v;
        }
      }
      r.breakApart();
    });

    let temp = "";
    let tempAr = [];
    const ar = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      const v = values[i][checkCol - 1];
      const row = i + 1;
      if (v == temp) {
        tempAr.push(row);
      } else {
        if (tempAr.length > 0) {
          ar.push(tempAr);
        }
        tempAr = [row];
        temp = v;
      }
      if (i == values.length - 1 && tempAr.length > 0) {
        ar.push(tempAr);
      }
    }
    ar.filter(r => r.length > 1).forEach(r => {
      const start = r.shift();
      const end = r.pop();
      const range = sheet.getRange(`${mergeColumns.start}${start}:${mergeColumns.end}${end}`);
      if (!range.isPartOfMerge()) {
        range.mergeVertically();
      }
    });

    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    Logger.log("Merging completed based on the second column match.");
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Merged cells successfully based on second column condition");
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log(`Error: ${error.message}`);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(`Error: ${error.message}`);
  }
}


In this modification, first, all merged cells are embedded by the values and cells are merged. And, the cells are merged again. By this, the additional rows can be processed.
Also, I modified the method for merging cells from merge to mergeVertically. By this, the process cost might be able to be reduced a little.

References:

Technique for Processing Google Spreadsheet Including Merged Cells using Google Apps Script
breakApart()
mergeVertically()

Added:
Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your current issue and your actual expected result, how about the following sample script?
function mergeCustomerOrderRows() {
  const spreadsheetId = "GOOGLE_SHEET_ID";
  const sheetName = "SHEET_NAME";
  const mergeColumns = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
  const checkCol = 2; // Column "B". This is from your script.

  try {
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName);
    const range = sheet.getDataRange();
    const values = range.getValues();
    const lastRow = sheet.getRange(range.getNumRows() - 1, 1, 1, range.getNumColumns());
    if (lastRow.isPartOfMerge()) {
      lastRow.getMergedRanges().forEach((r) => {
        const startRow = r.getRow() - 1;
        const endRow = startRow + r.getNumRows() - 1;
        const startCol = r.getColumn() - 1;
        const endCol = startCol + r.getNumColumns() - 1;
        const v = values[startRow][startCol];
        for (let r = startRow; r <= endRow; r++) {
          for (let c = startCol; c <= endCol; c++) {
            if (!values[r]) {
              values[r] = [];
            }
            values[r][c] = v;
          }
        }
        r.breakApart();
      });
    }
    let temp = "";
    let tempAr = [];
    const ar = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      const v = values[i][checkCol - 1];
      const row = i + 1;
      if (v == temp) {
        tempAr.push(row);
      } else {
        if (tempAr.length > 0) {
          ar.push(tempAr);
        }
        tempAr = [row];
        temp = v;
      }
      if (i == values.length - 1 && tempAr.length > 0) {
        ar.push(tempAr);
      }
    }
    ar.filter(r => r.length > 1).forEach(r => {
      const start = r.shift();
      const end = r.pop();
      mergeColumns.forEach(m => {
        const range = sheet.getRange(`${m}${start}:${m}${end}`);
        if (!range.isPartOfMerge()) {
          range.merge();
        }
      });
    });

    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    Logger.log("Merging completed based on the second column match.");
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Merged cells successfully based on second column condition");
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log(`Error: ${error.message}`);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(`Error: ${error.message}`);
  }
}


Hey @Tanaike, thanks for your response but with this approach, merged cells are remerging on every execution, whereas in the previous approach you provided, that wasn't happening. Only the unmerged cells were merging in that approach. Also, to let you know, I replaced the mergeColumn object with an array (along with the necessary modifications). This change allows me to skip any column to keep it unmerged, which isn’t possible with the current approach.

@Mikat Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue. Can I ask you about the details of your current issue? In order to correctly understand your current issue, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including the sample input and output situations? First, I would like to correctly understand your current issue, and modify the sample script. If you can coopearte to resolve your current issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

@Mikat Unfortunately, I'm still not sure whether I can correctly understand your current issue and your actual expected result. But, I added one more sample script in my answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful for your situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including the sample input and output situation? By this, I would like to confirm it.

I'm extremely sorry for my late response! The second script you added is partially doing the job, It's not remerging the previously merged cells except the last rows, though I'll take it as a answer, Thanks

@Mikat Thank you for replying. About The second script you added is partially doing the job, It's not remerging the previously merged cells except the last rows, though I'll take it as a answer, Thanks, unfortunately, when I tested my script using a sample Spreadsheet, the script works. So, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating your current issue?

No worries, I'm talking it as an answer

@Mikat Thank you for replying. I understand it. Thank you, too.
